# Why does EKS node becomes Unschedulable on its own

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster and a nodegroup running 6 nodes. For some reson nodes get marked as `unschedulable` randomly, once a week or two and they stay that way. When I notice that I uncordon them manually and everything works fine.

Why does this happen and how can I debug it, prevent it or configure cluster to fix it automatically?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how exactly did you setup your cluster? Please provide reproduction steps. Further, could you attach your logs? Did you even check them?

Comment: It's EKS version 1.20. Cluster is set up using EKS. I don't know how to reproduce it as it happens at random times without me doing anything. There are 300 pods running so I think it could be related to resource issue. Which logs should I be checking? I did not notice anything in K8s event log as when I notice the problem the events are already flooded with unrelated information. Please advise which logs would be relevant for such a case?

Comment: So how exactly did you set up your cluster? What exactly did you do inside it and how did you deploy those 300 pods. Look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/) and please attach logs from your scheduler. Marking a node as unschedulable prevents the scheduler from placing new pods onto that Node but does not affect existing Pods on the Node. This is useful as a preparatory step before a node reboot or other maintenance.

Comment: Hard to answer how it is configured, as it's a broad question. The nodegroup has spot instances except 1 ondemand node. There are Cronjobs that scale pods down in evenings, up in mornings, so issue could be related to resource overconsumption when cluster-autoscaler can't spawn new nodes fast enough. Regarding logs, I have enabled K8s control plane logging in EKS for scheduler, but can't find any relevant logs, searching by affected node name. Also worth to mention, that taint `node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule` is added when node gets marked unschedulable. It happened 2x this week.

Comment: The explanation in link below seems a likely reason, but I'm not sure how to debug or confirm it as having controllers in EKS control plane adds some complexity. Will enable all the control plane component logging and try to find the relevant logs. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#taint-nodes-by-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the problem was `AWS Termination Handler` daemonset that was running. It was outdated and not really used in the cluster and after removing it, problems with nodes getting marked Unschedulable just went away.